# log base 2 precision error

Tags: javascript, floating-point

I want to get mantissa of floating point number in JavaScript.

So I get exponent part of floating point number first.
By mathematics, exponent is `floor(log2(x))`.

However, There is no `log2` function in JavaScript.
So I make it from the natural logarithm. But the precision is matter.

Since `log2(pow(2, 3)) == 2.99999...`, `floor(log2(pow(2, 3)) == 2`.

How can I solve this problem? Thanks.

EDIT: I don't want to use `Math.log2` of ECMAScript6.

Comment: Please edit your code so that other can read it easily.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot operate with numbers in programming like in mathematics. There are some tricks and considerations, related to numbers precision.

For example, you shouldn't directly compare two numbers:

```
if (a === b) { ... } // wrong, 0.2999999999 !== 0.3
```

Instead, you need to check if the difference between them is less than something small:

```
var E = 0.000001;
if (Math.abs(a - b) < E) { ... } // right, abs(0.2999999999 - 0.3) < 0.000001
```

It will guarantee that numbers are compared with specified precision.

You can simply apply the same trick to round your number down correctly.
Since you floor your number down, then just add `E` to it beforehand.

```
var E = 0.000001;
var result = Math.floor(log2(pow(2, 3) + E); // it is 3, not 2
```

Note that this `E` value is an example.
You need to find a good `E` for your calculations: bigger `E` will result into worse precision, too small `E` will make it not work. If you work with big numbers which always round to integers, then you can use pretty big `E`.

Comment: For this example (`2.9999999` < 3) , the smallest `E` that make working is `0.000000000000001`  (`10**-15`); but I think since Javascript uses floating point values, then bigger will be the numbers to floor, bigger should be the corresponding E